# Matlab pcap2matlab function

Tags: matlab, networking

Given a pcap file I need to get the payloads of packets in Matlab. I read pcap2matlab does this but I couldn't understand the documentation properly. Can any one help me in this regard ?. If anyone used this function please explain to me both in capture mode and read mode.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the documentation on [pcap2matlab](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/44265-pcap2matlab---importing-network-protocol-analyzer-capabilties-into-matlab), you capture information directly from your network interface or you can use it in read mode where you read *.pcap files that you generate from a network logging utility such as Wireshark.

pcap2matlab looks like you should be able to use it in read only mode by reading in a filename directly, without any other parameters it should read directly into the EOF.
 From the docs.

> %           2.    A filename string that identifies the pcap file to read. Setting this input argument 
>   %               to a filename string will automatically set the function to work in read mode.

```
pcap2matlab('', '','filename.pcap')
```